# Floating images in the middle of text

Tags: html, css

How do I wrap text around an image like below?

```
+----------------------------+
|----[This is text]----------|
|----------------------------|
|-------+-----------+--------|
|-------|           |--------|
|-------|  [Image   |--------|
|-------|    here]  |--------|
|-------+-----------+--------|
|----------------------------|
|----------------------------|
|----------------------------|
|----------------------------|
+----------------------------+
```

Yeah, I know this could not be done, but wouldn't we enjoy if this feature would be provided in the future?

Comment: Sounds like OP wants an inset image and the text to reflow around it.

Comment: does [this](http://css-tricks.com/float-center/) help?

Comment: I'm a little surprised you didn't find Jakob's link helpful, because it's actually quite unnatural to break a sentence across an image.  The more natural thing is to split it into columns.  Doing so is far less likely to annoy your reader.

Comment: @user2253835 NO. You cannot do this with just html and css. You will need to break these up into columns to achieve the desired text wrapping as Jakob mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

There are no CSS properties that can accomplish this. The one kludgy thing I can think of is if you were using a monospaced font, you could probably sort something out with JavaScript, but it would be pretty complicated. It would involve finding the location of the image and manually whitespacing in behind it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using two different divisions, one to be placed to the right and the other to the left.